# Black screen after passphrase LUKS encryption

Tags: screen, disk, luks

I have a problem with ubuntu 22.04.
when i put passphrase to LUKS disk the screen becomes all black and I can't do anything. I am completely stuck.
What should I do?

Thanks for your consideration and help